# MalformedURLException while invoking SOAP xml from Katalon Studio

Tags: katalon-studio

MalformedURLException while invoking SOAP xml from Katalon Studio

> com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.exception.WebServiceException: java.lang.RuntimeException while invoking SOAP XML
>
> com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.exception.WebServiceException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: x
>       at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.common.SoapClient.parseWsdl(SoapClient.java:95)
>       at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.common.SoapClient.send(SoapClient.java:154)
>       at com.kms.katalon.controller.WebServiceController.sendRequest(WebServiceController.java:121)
>       at com.kms.katalon.composer.webservice.parts.SoapServicePart$4.run(SoapServicePart.java:237)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: x
>       at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.common.SoapClient$CustomWSDLLocator.getBaseInputSource(SoapClient.java:273)
>       at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
>       at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.common.SoapClient.parseWsdl(SoapClient.java:91)
>       ... 4 more
>   Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: x
>       at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.common.SoapClient$CustomWSDLLocator.load(SoapClient.java:310)
>       at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.common.SoapClient$CustomWSDLLocator.getBaseInputSource(SoapClient.java:270)
>       ... 6 more